# Post Interview Salary Negociation

Tags: interviewing, negotiation

During a job interview, I was asked about my salary expectations.

My preliminary expectations were too high, then the interviewer gave me some details about bonuses and such, and then I decreased my expectations.

Also, I came to realize that my idea about the job market is outdated, somehow, so salaries are not as high as they were 7 or 8 years ago.

Later on, I asked a friend who works there, they told me that they appreciate my resume, but the problem is with the salary.

Since I can contact the interviewer directly (through his business card): how should I proceed to show him that I am interested to hear their offer ?

Comment: Consider the possibility that salaries *are* as high as 7 or 8 years ago (and a fair bit higher depending on industry and location) but that for whatever reason this company isn't offering a competitive salary.

Answer (score 5):

> Since I can contact the interviewer directly (through his business
>   card): how should I proceed to show him that I am interested to hear
>   their offer ?

Assuming you haven't yet been formally dropped from consideration by the hiring manager, call or send an email.

Indicate that you are excited about the possibility of working there, and that you hope you can reach a compromise on salary.

Then, hope for the best.

It's possible that you overplayed your hand and that your expectations have already ruled you out. But it's also possible that following up will hint that you are willing to settle for less than you first suggested.